# Debugging Hadoop reducer OutOfMemoryError

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, memory-leaks, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to debug an `OutOfMemoryError` I'm getting in my Hadoop reducers. The mappers complete successfully. They generate small records that are less than 128 bytes. In my reducer, I collect records with the same key (there around 15 possible keys), and write them to separate output files with `MultipleOutputs`. The distribution of records per key isn't uniform.

In the middle of the reduce phase, I start getting `OutOfMemoryErrors`. I've checked a lot of things:

- The reducer doesn't save data; once it gets a value, it writes it out to the corresponding output
- I tried different values for the number of reduce tasks. Tuning this is a bit weird in my case because more than 15 won't help because there are only 15 keys
- Instantiating `MultipleOutputs` and closing it *in `reduce()`*, thinking it holds onto resources for the output files. This only works because keys and output files have a one-to-one mapping.
- I tried adding data to the end of the keys so the data would get distributed evenly between reduce tasks
- Out of paranoia, `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent=0`
- Verified keys and values really are small
- Disabled output compression, thinking there's a memory leak in the compressor
- Blindly tuning things like `mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent`

I'm not sure where else memory could be going other than aggressively buffering the shuffle output.

This is running on GCP Dataproc with Hadoop 3.2.2. A lot of guides recommend setting `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`. I tried this unsuccessfully, but I also assume Google chose a reasonable default for the host size, and I don't have a convincing story about where the memory's going. My one other theory is something in `GoogleHadoopOutputStream` that writes to cloud store is buffering. I have some output files between 10GB and 100GB--larger than the memory of the machine.

What else should I look at? Are these other flags I should try to tune? Attaching VisualVM doesn't look easy, but would a heap dump help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `GoogleHadoopOutputStream` consumes around ~70 MiB of JVM heap because it uploads data to Google Cloud Storage in 64 MiB chunks by default. That's why if you are writing many objects in the same MR task using `MultipleOutputs`, each task will need `number of outputs x 70 MiB` JVM heap.

You can reduce memory consumed by each `GoogleHadoopOutputStream` via [`fs.gs.outputstream.upload.chunk.size` property](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/v2.2.0/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md#io-configuration) but this will reduce upload speed to Google Cloud Storage too, that's why a better approach will be to re-factor your MR job to write a single/fewer files in each MR task.

Comment: I checked a heap dump, and you nailed it. I'll also look into writing fewer files per task.

Comment: Thank you Igor I was struggling with a similar problem using multiple outputs in Hadoop Map/Reduce Job using Dataproc and saving outputs on Google Cloud Storage. The error was `Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted ...` and `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space ...`. If you have the same error try what Igor said reduce memory consumed by updating this property fs.gs.outputstream.upload.chunk.size or do some refactoring to try to reduce the number of differents outputs file in the reducer.